# BadCertificateHostNameInvalid in UA-expert after adding UserManager to OPCUA server

Tags: node.js, opc-ua, node-opcua

I'm experiencing a `BadCertificateHostNameInvalid` when accessing to my opcua server through UaExpert after I try to change my server configuration using user manager and security policy Basic256Sha256 and `messageSecurityMode` `SignAndEncrypt`. Before this changes I used to have `allowAnonymous` on False and `securityModes` on none. also I used to secure my server with `certificateFiles`.
This error I get is just like a warning, I can ignore it and my server works fine but I would like to avoid it. I copy an image of the warning here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ggWw.png)

Code before:

```
allowAnonymous: True
certificateFile: certificateFile
privateKeyFile: privateKeyFile
securityPolicies: None
securityMode: None
```

Code After:

```
allowAnonymous: False
certificateFile: certificateFile
privateKeyFile: privateKeyFile
securityPolicies: Basic256Sha256
securityMode: SignAndEncrypt
userManager: userManager
```

Resume:

I try to add `userManager` to my server and we are having an error with `BadCertificateHostNameInvalid` code.
I expect to don't get this error and have the server working properly with this new user configuration apart from the certificates.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a certificate for the server, with a AlternativeSubjectName that contains the hostname/dnsname of the server, to get ride of the error message.

When you use SecurityPolicy None then no certificate is used in the communication, so there is no error.

Comment: But can i use SecurityPolicy None with userManager?

Comment: Yes, you can use SecurityPolicy=None with userManager,. 
When doing so, the data flow between the server and the client will not be encrypted, however OPCUA is designed to make sure that the secret (such as the  password) are nethertheless encrypted using the asymetric encryption during the ActivateSession transaction. The client and server certificates/private keys will be involved in encrypting/decrypting the password.